# Improve csv-import time MySQL Workbench

Tags: python, mysql, performance, csv-import

My goal is to import a csv file with MySQL workbench. The file consists of around 10.5 million rows and 29 columns in total 3,2GB. I have managed to import the file with the LOAD DATA INFILE command but it takes around 20 minutes which is by far too long. What can I do to speed up the import time? I was thinking of importing several parts of the file at once but don't know how to implement that. Here's my query so far:

```
CREATE TABLE test (
Betriebspunkt INT,
Bohru DOUBLE,
C_k DOUBLE,
Drehzahl INT,
Hub DOUBLE,
Lambda DOUBLE,
T_Start INT,
eps INT,
m_Luft INT,
pll DOUBLE,
x_AGR INT,
phi_10 VARCHAR(25),
phi_50 VARCHAR(25),
phi_90 VARCHAR(25),
phi_10_90 VARCHAR(25),
pmi_HD_Shelby DOUBLE,
p_Start DOUBLE,
p_max DOUBLE,
phi_p_max DOUBLE,
dp_max DOUBLE,
phi_dp_max DOUBLE,
p_Ende DOUBLE,
T_Ende DOUBLE,
max_dQ_B DOUBLE,
NO DOUBLE,
Lambda_Ende,
Konvergenz_SWP DOUBLE,
iterIV INT,
Ik_E_FKFS VARCHAR(25),
PRIMARY KEY(Betriebspunkt)
);

LOAD DATA INFILE 'C:/Users/l-reh/Desktop/Bachelorarbeit/DB Testdatensatz/Testdatensatz_FKFS_Python.csv' INTO TABLE test
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
ENCLOSED BY '"' 
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
IGNORE 1 ROWS;
```

Comment: *it takes around 20 minutes wich is by far too long* This is ~3 Mbytes/second. This is a norma because your table structure contains primary index. Try to remove PK and add it after data importing (or maybe you don't need it at all?).

Comment: thanks for your're quick response! i removed the PK and it got faster by 40sec. but i was hoping to complete the import in under 5 min.

Comment: *i removed the PK and it got faster by 40sec.* If so than you have some problem with memory amount or disk subsystem, maybe even in OS. In normal state the rate of importing is 10-20 Mb/s on even weak system.